# Integrate clamAV into laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement clamAV into laravel. After running all requirement, still it does not work. Have tried using the command line option which works, but need the solution for implementing it with the laravel validator.

On file upload on the server side I need to scan the file using clamAV before it is store into file system.

Have tried using the command line option which works, but need the solution for implementing it with the laravel validator.

Comment: Why not validate a file before passing it to the command line? As far as letting Laravel really work together with ClamAV: this is not possible as ClamAV is a binary. You can only send commands and read the output through execution.

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful diagnostic. Where is your code? You do know that you can't change the Laravel validators - you need to use the after validation hook.

Comment: Terminal Command                                                                   
      clamscan -i --max-scansize=4000M --max-filesize=4000M <file-path>
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 6769886
Engine version: 0.100.2
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 1
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.18 MB
Data read: 0.04 MB (ratio 4.27:1)
Time: 14.016 sec (0 m 14 s)                                                                                 
Is not that before storing a file into file system it has to be scanned. So I think terminal command does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Laravel clamav scanner

https://github.com/sunspikes/clamav-validator